# Error running BITCOIND in Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop under Oracle VirtualBox in Windows 7 64bit I get the following error:

```
sim@sim-VirtualBox:~/bitcoin-0.8.5-linux/bin/32$ ./bitcoind -rpcpassword=12345 **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: File exists: "/home/sim/.bitcoin"
Aborted (core dumped)**
```

Anyone know how I can fix this or what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a file named `.bitcoin.` in your root directory? If so, delete it with `rm /home/sim/.bitcoin` and try running the server again.

Comment: That did it! So far so good. I'm just trying to get the wallet from Windows imported... I'm assuming a wallet.dat is interchangeable b/w linux and windows?

Comment: Usually they are, but there's some edge cases with Berkely DB compatibility that will cause opening to fail. You'll know if it doesn't work. Just shut down the node, swap in your old `wallet.dat`, and do a `-rescan` if your node was up to date when you did the sync.